# How many divisors of N ended by 5

Tags: arithmetic

I must know how to find how many divisor of N ended by 5 ? In my exercise, I have $\ N=63'000 = 2^3*3^2*5^3*7 $ and I can found the number of divisors of N using $\ (3+1)*(2+1)*(3+1)*(1+1)=96$

Among these 96 divisors, how many ended by 5 ? How can calculate this ?

Thank you so much

Comment: The ones that have at least one factor $5$, and at the same time no factor $2$ will end in $5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take out the $2$s, because when multiplied by $5$, the result will end with $0$.
2. Find the number of divisors of $3^2\cdot7^1$, which is $(2+1)\cdot(1+1)=6$:

   - $3^0\cdot7^0$
   - $3^1\cdot7^0$
   - $3^2\cdot7^0$
   - $3^0\cdot7^1$
   - $3^1\cdot7^1$
   - $3^2\cdot7^1$
3. Multiply each divisor by each one of the following $3$ powers of $5$:

   - $5^1$
   - $5^2$
   - $5^3$
4. Hence you have $6\cdot3=18$ divisors which end with $5$:

   - $3^0\cdot7^0\cdot5^1$
   - $3^1\cdot7^0\cdot5^1$
   - $3^2\cdot7^0\cdot5^1$
   - $3^0\cdot7^1\cdot5^1$
   - $3^1\cdot7^1\cdot5^1$
   - $3^2\cdot7^1\cdot5^1$
   - $3^0\cdot7^0\cdot5^2$
   - $3^1\cdot7^0\cdot5^2$
   - $3^2\cdot7^0\cdot5^2$
   - $3^0\cdot7^1\cdot5^2$
   - $3^1\cdot7^1\cdot5^2$
   - $3^2\cdot7^1\cdot5^2$
   - $3^0\cdot7^0\cdot5^3$
   - $3^1\cdot7^0\cdot5^3$
   - $3^2\cdot7^0\cdot5^3$
   - $3^0\cdot7^1\cdot5^3$
   - $3^1\cdot7^1\cdot5^3$
   - $3^2\cdot7^1\cdot5^3$

Comment: what about those with out $5$-factor like $21$?

Comment: You still allow for a factorization with no $5$ in it. It should be $(2+1)(3)(1+1)$

Comment: @OfirSchnabel: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer. I just not understand why I must get rid of $\ 2^3 $ and keep the others ? And in my correction, the answer is 18

Comment: @CyrillGremaud: $2$ and $5$ together will make the divisor end with $0$.

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Also, $3\cdot 4 \cdot 2 = 24$, and $3 \cdot 2 = 6$.

Comment: @Arthur: Yep... I've completely revised the answer (was too hasty submitting it).